# ASP.NET Web API returns only one object in collection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have the following action in my ASP.NET Web API:

```
    public IEnumerable<Car> carssOfUser(int id, String username, String password)
    {

        using (var context = new CarEntities())
        {
            // Authorization. Allow user only to get his own cars
            User userQueried = context.Users.Where(u => u.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (!userQueried.username.Equals(username))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                //return null;
            }

            IEnumerable<Car> cars = context.Cars.Where(p => p.ownerId == id).ToList();
            return cars;
        }
    }
```

However, if I query it from Android application to obtain cars of given users (through json).. let's say with id 2, it returns collection of 9 cars (that's correct, user 2 has 9 cars), but only first car has proper field values (name, price etc.), the rest of cars have null in all fields.

That's really strange, cause the problem happened when I added these lines of code:

```
// Authorization. Allow user only to get his own cars
            User userQueried = context.Users.Where(u => u.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (!userQueried.username.Equals(username))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                //return null;
            }
```

After removing it, everything works perfectly fines and all cars have proper values in fields (not nulls anymore)...

Do you have any idea how to explain this imo very strange behavior?

I don't think it matters (cause all other actions where I don't have this kind of authorization works without problems), but I want to mention that from Android app I use gson to deserialize, and on server side I use JSON.NET to serialize.

Comment: in your second code sample you will throw the exception if the username matches that of the found user

Comment: Yep, that's just a typo. (the code in the snippet above it was correct). Corrected the second snippet as well.

Comment: have you tried to pull the cars first and do the authorization check after that? that's really strange behavior. Is your CarEntities the only context object? Are you using EDM and have some specific association configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the database access code and I put authorization code into using statement:

```
    using (var context = new GeoDiaryEntities())
    {
        // Authorization. Allow user only to get his own travels
        User userQueried = context.Users.Where(u => u.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (!userQueried.username.Equals(username))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
```

It helped and it works now.
However, I'm not really sure why executing this code within separate context helped..
any ideas?